# error when i try to use webengine module in qt

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-creator, qtwebengine

Hellow everyone recently i'am trying  to  use qtwebengine in qt but every time i get an error
this is my code  :

```
#include <QApplication>
#include<QtWebEngineWidgets/QtWebEngineWidgets>>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWebEngineView j;
    j.setUrl(QUrl("elodream.herokuapp.com"));
    j.resize(600,600);
    j.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

error :

```
main.obj:-1: erreur : LNK2019: symbole externe non r‚solu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QQmlDebuggingEnabler::QQmlDebuggingEnabler(bool)" (__imp_??0QQmlDebuggingEnabler@@QEAA@_N@Z) r‚f‚renc‚ dans la fonction "void __cdecl `dynamic initializer for 'qQmlEnableDebuggingHelper''(void)" (??__EqQmlEnableDebuggingHelper@@YAXXZ)
main.obj:-1: erreur : LNK2019: symbole externe non r‚solu "__declspec(dllimport) public: __cdecl QWebEngineView::QWebEngineView(class QWidget *)" (__imp_??0QWebEngineView@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) r‚f‚renc‚ dans la fonction main
main.obj:-1: erreur : LNK2019: symbole externe non r‚solu "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl QWebEngineView::~QWebEngineView(void)" (__imp_??1QWebEngineView@@UEAA@XZ) r‚f‚renc‚ dans la fonction main
main.obj:-1: erreur : LNK2019: symbole externe non r‚solu "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __cdecl QWebEngineView::setUrl(class QUrl const &)" (__imp_?setUrl@QWebEngineView@@QEAAXAEBVQUrl@@@Z) r‚f‚renc‚ dans la fonction main
C:\Users\Pc\Documents\build-Jstore-Desktop_Qt_6_2_4_MSVC2019_64bit-Debug\debug\Jstore.exe:-1: erreur : LNK1120: 4 externes non r‚solus
C:\Users\Pc\Documents\Jstore\main.cpp:3: avertissement : Extra tokens at end of #include directive (fix available)
```

Comment: Looks like the problem is in the libraries you are linking. You should show your .pro file since that is where you have the bug.

Comment: The first table in the manual [QWebEngineView Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebengineview.html)

Comment: That document at the top in the qmake line of the table shows that you need to add `QT += webenginewidgets` to your `.pro`